# How to remove Fork me on Github from the downloaded code?

Tags: github

I am new to Github. Recently I have downloaded a code for Node js from Github and when I run it, there is banner "Fork me on Github" in the right corner. How can I remove that?

```
<img id="github-banner" alt="Fork me on GitHub" src="https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/7afbc8b248c68eb468279e8c17986ad46549fb71/687474703a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f6769746875622f726962626f6e732f666f726b6d655f72696768745f6461726b626c75655f3132313632312e706e67" style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0;border:0;">
```

This is the code I get when I inspect it. But I could not find it. I searched the whole folder contents.

Please help me. Thanks in Advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find the code inside the project HTML files which should be similar to the snippets on the [GitHub Ribbons blog post](https://github.com/blog/273-github-ribbons) and remove this code.

If you search for `https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons`, you should find the ribbon code.

Comment: Or maybe use the 'inspect element' menu item from the context menu to locate it.

Comment: How did you search for the code (using a text editor or Finder/Windows Explorer) and could you provide a link to the GitHub page where you downloaded the code?

Answer (score 1):

That part is integrated in the site code. look for something like:

```
    <a href="http://github.com/USER"><img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_right_red_aa0000.png" alt="Fork me on GitHub" /></a>
```

more details here:
https://github.com/blog/273-github-ribbons

Comment: Then look for links starting with `https://` or `http://` . The script might be inserted from another source with jQuery. Check all external links in your code and remove the banner code inject.